# JavaScript code executes multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, python, image-processing, cgi

I have created a simple webpage that does basic image processing. I have used php to upload the images and Python (cgi-scripting) to resize them if their width or height is over 600px or 400px respectively (via ajax calls).

#### Here's the scenario:

1. User selects the image.
2. User hits the upload button.
3. This makes an ajax call to `upload.php` that uploads the file to the server.
4. On success, another ajax call to `resize.py`(cgi-scripting) is made to resize the image if the image is bigger than the max width and height.
5. On success, the resized image is drawn to the canvas.
6. User hits the `Run` button. (Image changes to GrayScale).
7. User hits the `Reset` button. (Original Image is drawn to the canvas).

*Everything until here works fine.*

Now, if the user selects another image, uploads it and hits the `Run` button, the function that is triggered by this `Run` button event is executed twice. If the `Reset` button is pressed, the function that is triggered by this event is executed 3 times.

If the 3<sup>rd</sup> image is uploaded, the `Run` button event is executed 3 times when the `Run` button is pressed and if the `Reset` button is pressed, the function gets executed 6 times. It keeps on adding if another image is uploaded.

I have two other image effects and the same problem with them as well. I can't figure out how to fix this problem. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? How do I solve this problem?

### See the code in action (Last slide):

```
http://#########/Main/JS/javascript.html
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#grayscaleButtonUpload').click(function() {

  var input = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
  imageName = input.value;
  var file = input.files[0];

  if(file != undefined) {
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
      formData.append("image", file);

      // Make the ajax call to upload the image
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
          var input = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
          imageName = input.value;
          var file = input.files[0];
          formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("filename", file.name);

          // Make the ajax call to resize the image
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://##########/Main/cgi-bin/resize.py",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              var grayscaleCanvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
              var grayscaleCtx = grayscaleCanvas.getContext("2d");
              var grayscaleImage = new Image();

              grayscaleImage.src = "http://###########/Main/JS/upload/" + file.name;
              $(grayscaleImage).load(function() {

                if (!grayscaleCanvas.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('imageCanvas').toDataURL()) {
                    grayscaleCtx.clearRect(0, 0, grayscaleCanvas.width, grayscaleCanvas.height);
                    $('#imageCanvas').css({"border":"none", "border-color": "none"});
                };

                grayscaleCanvas.width = grayscaleImage.width;
                grayscaleCanvas.height = grayscaleImage.height;
                grayscaleCtx.drawImage(grayscaleImage, 0, 0);
                $('#imageCanvas').css({"border":"ridge", "border-color": "green"});

                // Run button event
                $("#grayscaleButtonRun").click(function() {
                  console.log('Run button pressed')
                  var grayscaleImageData = grayscaleCtx.getImageData(0, 0, grayscaleCanvas.width, grayscaleCanvas.height);
                  var grayscalepixels = grayscaleImageData.data;
                  var grayscaleNumPixels = grayscaleImageData.width * grayscaleImageData.height;

                  for (var i = 0; i < grayscaleNumPixels; i++) {
                    var avg = (grayscalepixels[i * 4] + grayscalepixels[i * 4 + 1] + grayscalepixels[i * 4 + 2]) / 3;
                    grayscalepixels[i * 4] = avg;
                    grayscalepixels[i * 4 + 1] = avg;
                    grayscalepixels[i * 4 + 2] = avg;
                  };

                  grayscaleCtx.clearRect(0, 0, grayscaleCanvas.width, grayscaleCanvas.height);
                  grayscaleCtx.putImageData(grayscaleImageData, 0, 0);

                  // Reset button event
                  $('#grayscaleButtonReset').click(function() {
                    console.log('Reset button pressed')
                    grayscaleCtx.clearRect(0, 0, grayscaleCanvas.width, grayscaleCanvas.height);
                    grayscaleCanvas.width = grayscaleImage.width;
                    grayscaleCanvas.width = grayscaleImage.width;
                    grayscaleCtx.drawImage(grayscaleImage, 0, 0);
                  });
                });
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Selected file is not an image!');
    }
  } else {
  alert('No File Selected!');  
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, you're adding a new `click` handler to the same button over and over, but you never remove the old one. They stack, you know.

Comment: How could I solve the problem?

Comment: The right way is to attach each handler once, when the page is loaded (or when the button is dynamically attached to the page DOM). However, a quick hack is to use .off (http://api.jquery.com/off/) to clear handlers of a particular type inside the handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Learned something new today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are adding new `click` handlers to the buttons without removing the ones that were there.

Ideally, you should add each handler exactly once: on pageload for static elements, and on DOM insertion for dynamically-created elements.

Alternatively, a hacky workaround is to use `.off` (the opposite of `.on`) to remove all handlers of a particular type from an element just before adding a new one.